# Lottery iOS App

Tags: australia, gambling, lotteries

Would Apple allow an app where you can purchase a lottery ticket through PayPal and go into the chance to win, with the winners money going to a PayPal account?

What are the legal considerations when it comes to lottery apps in Australia?

Comment: Beyond the gambling regulatory issues, you would also be faced with the issue that Apple would probably not allow payment for such a "service" via Paypal, but would instead require use of in-app purchases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In NSW and all other Australian jurisdictions lotteries and other games of chance are regulated. See https://www.liquorandgaming.justice.nsw.gov.au/Pages/gaming/competitions/games-of-chance.aspx

In general, lottery type games can only be run for the benefit of charities or by registered clubs. Free entry games can be run as trade promotions.

Straight lotteries are restricted to the State or specific enterprises licenced by the State.

The legal considerations of what you are proposing is that you will be fined or sent to gaol.

Comment: Adding to Dale's excellent answer, here are the terms of service from Apple on this issue. https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#contests